# Shared service requests records between users in application View Self Service

Tags: maximo

Is there any possibility for users in application View Service Request to see all the service requests under the common vendor.

Example: 
User 1 belongs to vendor A.
User 2 belongs to vendor A.
User 1 create a service request, where the record contain vendor A.

The request must be visible to User 1 and User 2 in application View Service Request.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

No. Or, at least, you shouldn't go down this road uninformed.

View Service Request is a "self-service" application, designed to support Self-Service licensing. Under that licensing, User 1 is only permitted to see service requests raised by User 1, and removing that restriction is a violation of licensing. If all of your users have (and will only ever have) licenses greater than Self-Service licenses, then this may not be a concern for you.